# GCC compiler infrastructure for VLIW architectures

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, cross-platform, vliw

Do you know how strong VLIW architectures support exists in GCC compiler infrastructure? I know that there are some VLIW architectures supported by GCC. Looking at them, it seems that the pipeline optimizations are left to another optimization layer. Are there good (not GCC internals doc) materials on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There indeed are VLIW targets supported by GCC: on the current trunk, this includes at least [FRV](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/FRV-Options.html), [MeP](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/MeP-Options.html) and [picoChip](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/picoChip-Options.html). The support include optimization. As they are not "mainstream" targets (i.e. [primary or secondary targets](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.5/criteria.html)), there might be some suboptimal code generation for them in some cases.